# Ubuntu 12.10 is terribly slow

Tags: 12.10

I have 2.5G intel cpu and 3G ram. But click any button in live cd version need to wait 3 minutes. My dvd is burned.

Comment: Everything is slower in the live-cd version. Just install it 0o

Answer (score 2):

This is a known effect of using a LiveCD. Install Ubuntu to get a more responsive version.